# How to pass a string as a tag of UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios

The tag value is an Integer:

```
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setTitle:addressField forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(pickTheQuiz:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.tag=1;//or what other integer value, i need to put a string value
```

In the receiver method:

```
-(void)pickTheQuiz:(id)sender{           
    NSLog(@"The part number is:%i",((UIControl*)sender).tag);//i need to receive a string value instead of numeric value
}
```

Comment: *Why* do you need to do that? `tag` is an integer, so you are not going to be able to set a string there at all. But I reiterate - please tell us why you need to do that as there's highly likely a better solution.

Comment: you can not parse string value in tag

Comment: ok, lets say that i need to pass the `addressField` value when the button is pressed. How can i do that? thanx in advance :)

Comment: I need a tag to pass the PictureID value when the button is pressed, however the PictureID in our system can NOT be assumed as an Integer, how can apple guys assume people should only pass an Integer?!

Comment: Create a mapping from tags to whatever you want. `NSDictionary* lookup = @{ @(tag1) : object1 , @(tag2) : object2};` When you get a tag value back, look up the corresponding object: `id object = lookup[@(tag_value)];`

Answer (score 12):

You can convert the integer value of a tag to a NSString with:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", ((UIControl*)sender).tag];
```

Or, if you really need a string as identifier for an UI object, just subclass it and add a property like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *stringID;
```

And then use it instead of use the tag property.

Answer (score 8):

You can do that as bellow with the help of feature objc_runtime

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static char kButtonAssociatedKey;

NSString *aStrKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Any Key"];
UIButton *button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setTitle:addressField forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(pickTheQuiz:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.tag=1;

objc_setAssociatedObject(button,
                         &kButtonAssociatedKey,
                         aStrKey,
                         OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);

-(void)pickTheQuiz:(id)sender
{
    NSString *aStrKey = objc_getAssociatedObject(sender, &kButtonAssociatedKey);
    objc_removeAssociatedObjects(sender);
    NSLog(@"%@", aStrKey);
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Too bad apple has not added this as a method on NSObject

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the Best Answer for this Question.

Answer (score 1):

The tag property will only accept integers, and if hacking the integer value to get to a string is not an option for you, you can sub-class the UIButton, and then use the User Defined Runtime Attributes section in IB to set the value of the property in your StoryBoard.

Subclass the UIButton with a new non-integer property:

> ```
> @interface MyCustomUIButton : UIButton
>
> @property (strong) NSString* stringTag;
>
> @end
> ```

Set your button's class to the sub-class:

> Identity inspector > Custom Class > Class => MyCustomUIButton

Set the property value from IB OR through code:

From IB:

> Identity inspector > User Defined Runtime Attributes:
>
> Key Path => stringTag
>
> Type => String
>
> Value => yourstringvalue

OR From Code:

```
((MyCustomUIButton*)yourButton).stringTag = @"yourstringvalue";
```

Then you can retrieve the value of the property from your button action method:

```
-(void)yourMethod:(id)sender
    {           
     NSLog(@"The string value is: ",((MyCustomUIButton*)sender).stringTag);

    // or use this idiom, to avoid a possible crash if it's the wrong class:

    if ( [sender respondsToSelector:@selector(stringTag)] )
          testeee = [sender valueForKey:@"stringTag"];
    else
          NSLog(@"this IS NOT a MyCustomUIButton, it's a plain UIButton");

    // testeee will be NULL if you FORGOT to set the
    // User Defined Runtime Attribute for 'stringTag' in storyboard

    // note that a useful alternative to
    // if ( [sender respondsToSelector:@selector(stringTag)] )
    // is... 
    // if ( [sender respondsToSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"stringTag")] )
    }
```

Comment: Hiya Justas!  Just to be clear, you MUST USE a custom class, is that correct Justas?  You can't simply set a "User Defined Runtime Attributes" to some key/value, and then pick that up using valueForKey -- that's right?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

NSLog(@"The part number is:%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(UIControl*)sender).tag]);

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know tags are always type int.

youll need to convert it manually like:

```
NSString *temp : [[NSString alloc]init];
if(sender.tag == x){
    temp = @"some string";
)
```

and make cases for the different tags.

please correct me if im wrong here :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
-(void)pickTheQuiz:(id)sender{           
 NSNumber *tag = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag];
  NSLog(@"The part number is:%@",[tag stringValue]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way for passing a NSString parameter with uibutton i.e. just set title of buuton with clear color and font size 0.0f.This is valid if your using a image([button setBackgroundImage:anyImage. forState:UIControlStateNormal];) on button and not showing the titl and then you can get "sender.currentTitle" and use this variable

Answer (score 0):

Probably not best practice, but one simple way to pass a string with `UIButton` is to store it in the `accessibilityIdentifier` property.

```
yourButton.accessibilityIdentifier = "Some string you want to pass"
```

...

```
@objc func tappedButton(sender: UIButton) {
  print("passed string is: \(sender.accessibilityIdentifier)")
}
```