# how to send string value in uibutton

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some anotation in google map , i have to send those latitude and longitude value on button selecter ito another mathod, i have tried to set in "tag" but it's returning null value, any idea why

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", annotation.coordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude];

       // NSLog(@"%@",str);

        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        rightButton.frame = CGRectMake(30, 0, 32, 32);
        [rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"getdirections.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
        return annotationView;
```

Thnks in advance

Comment: Try: How to pass a string as a tag of UIButton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632040/how-to-pass-a-string-as-a-tag-of-uibutton

Comment: u mean, u want to send info to another viewcontroller when rightCalloutAccessoryView button tapped >>>??

Comment: @iPatel Hi man, no in another method

Comment: Sry, but I think that nobody exactly knows what you want to do... Can you explain it in another (a better) way?