# Assign string to UIButton's tag value

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton

I wanted to give a string value to `UIButton` tag for unique identities.
I tried this code.But it doesnt work.

```
    NSString *A;
    NSString *B;
    NSString *C;
    NSString *D;

    firstOptionABtn.tag=[A integerValue];
    secondOptonBbtn.tag=[B integerValue];
    thirdOptionCbtn.tag=[C integerValue];
    fourthOptionDbtn.tag=[D integerValue];  

   - (IBAction)BtnClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
     NSLog(@"%ld",(long)sender.tag);
   }
```

I don't like this way but it will print 0 every time. Where am I going wrong? 
Please help. Thanks

Comment: downvoter why downvoting me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a string as a tag of UIButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632040/how-to-pass-a-string-as-a-tag-of-uibutton)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What need to use string for set tag value of button... why not set tag of Button statically simply set like :-

```
firstOptionABtn.tag=1;
```

First time seen this setting tag with string to int convert

In your queston First is you are not seting the value of you string

```
NSString *A;
NSString * B;
NSString * C;
NSString * D;
```

if you set value of string like

```
A=@"2"
```

then your code working and you got the value at the button click event

```
firstOptionABtn.tag=[A integerValue];
```

its output is

**sender tag 2**

Into you String value consider any Number value then the covert string to Intiger cosider only Number not alphabet character like

**for example**

> If you set value of string like A=@"2aaabbb" then the output of button tag is **2** But if you set string value like A=@"bb2aaabbb" then output of button tag is Always 0 consider.

**UPDATE**

if you wish to set character to int
you can convert  `NSString to ASCII` Like Bellow

```
 A=@"A"
 int ASCIINumber = [A characterAtIndex:0];
 button.tag=ASCIINumber;
```

**OUTPUT IS:- 65 for Upper case if lower case OUTPUT IS 97**

But as using above method i suggest to you use simply set `tag=intNumber` instead of doing above.

Comment: ya i know the tag value is always stored in int but i just to learn thats why i am asking this question.

Comment: ABCD is not consider as an Integer value that return always 0 if you are try to convert string to Integer. so better to use int Number value. check my updated answer that i explain fully

Comment: But what if tag is like @"xyz" ? then [A integerValue] wont work...and anyways characters and strings are not allowed for tagging.

Comment: Button.tag is consider integer not string and `xyz` is a string not a int. int consider only Numerical value not alphabet.

Answer (score 3):

It returns zero as you did not initialize string, and it has null value when you convert it into integer it returns you zero. And it seems that you create your button from NIB so you can set their tag value from there and then get there value by implementing.

```
-( IBAction )buttonClicked:(id)sender 
{
    UIButton *btn= (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"%d",btn.tag);
}
```

but  if u want the output A,B,C, D then there is also a way

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

  btn1.accessibilityLabel=@"A";
  btn2.accessibilityLabel=@"B";
  btn3.accessibilityLabel=@"C";
  btn4.accessibilityLabel=@"D";

}

-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

    UIButton *btn= (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"%@",btn.accessibilityLabel);
}
```

output is A, B, C, D

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible dear to set string in tag. Tag only takes int value as you said you know.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom view which is composed of `UIButton` and a `NSString` property or an ivar which will serve as `tag`.

```
@interface MyButton: UIView

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIButton *button; 
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *uniqueTag;

@end
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

we can make a category for tag string in `UIButton`.

```
@interface UIButton (setTag)

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *tagString;

@end
```

And any where in your file you can set the tag string to your UIButton.
e.g

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[btn setTagString:@"Hello"];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always create a custom class containing a string property to go along with said classes

for example : create a custom class for UIButton

and then at the Header File put :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSString *labelTag;

 - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withLabelTag:(NSString *)str;
```

and then, at the implementation create a super method of init with frame so it looked like this :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withLabelTag:(NSString *)str{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        //Init code
        _labelTag = str;
    }
    return self;
}
```

after that, whenever you want to set or call the string tag of the button you only need to declare it and call it like this :

```
MyCustomButton *button = [[MyCustomButton alloc]initWithFrame:frame withLabelTag:@"this is the title"];

//and to call it :
NSLog (@"the button's tag is :%@", button.labelTag)
```

or, you could always just use the button's title property and if you don't want it to show on your button, just set its HIDDEN prop to YES

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios.

**Case 1:** If your tag string contains only numbers - (Eg: `tagStringValue = "1433"`)

Use `myButton.tag = [tagStringValue intValue];`

Get back the button using

```
UIButton *myButton = ([[self.view viewWithTag:[tagStringValue intValue]] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])?(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:[tagStringValue intValue]]:nil;
```

**Case 2:** If your tag string contains numbers and strings - (Eg: `tagStringValue = "ss1433kk"`)

Subclass the UIButton and add a property like:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *stringTag;` and use this instead of default `Tag`.