# Identify a button with a String

Tags: objective-c

I've read, that when you want to identify a button that has been clicked you can simply use

`button.tag = 10` as an example. The problem I'm occuring now, is, that I need to use a string as identifier, since the id comes from a server, that uses words and numbers in its identifier to make it unique. The problem I have now, is that I don't really now how I could identify the button since tag is only for integers. I can't just iterate it because it has to be fully dynamic. What would be the way to go?

I've read this link right here
[How to pass a string as a tag of UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632040/how-to-pass-a-string-as-a-tag-of-uibutton)

and it said something of subclasses, but I'm fairly new to Objective-C so I don't know if that's to haard for a beginner!

**Edit of the code after suggestions from user @Greg**

```
//Class: CustomButton.h
@interface CustomButton : UIButton
@property ( nonatomic, retain ) NSString *stringTag;
@end

//Class: MainViewController.m
#import "CustomButton.h"
//code
CustomButton *testButton    = [CustomButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
testButton.frame            = CGRectMake( 15.0f, _counterForLists, 250.0f, 30.0f  );

[testButton addTarget           :self action:@selector( deleteListItem:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[testButton setBackgroundColor  :[UIColor blackColor]];
[testButton setTitleColor       :[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[testButton setTitle            :[projectData description] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

testButton.stringTag = @"TEST";
_counterForLists += 30;
[self.view addSubview:testButton      ];

 //Method deleteListItem (When I press the button it crashes)

- (void)deleteListItem:(CustomButton *)sender{
    NSLog(@"Button clicked with ID: %@", sender.stringTag);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create subclass of UIButton and add a identifier property:

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *tagAsString;
@end
```

And every time where you use UIButton replace it with MyButton, for example:
Old code

```
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 50, 30)];
    [btn setTitle:@"Your title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.tag = 1;
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view btn];
```

with:

```
        MyButton *btn = [MyButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 50, 30)];
        [btn setTitle:@"Your title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.tagAsString = @"string as a identifier";
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view btn];
```

And you can still use tag property.

//EXTENDED

You cannot use standard method like viewWithTag:, you should create your own, for example:

```
-(MyButton*)buttonForTag:(NSString*)tagAsString
{
    for (UIView *v in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[MyButton class]])
        {
            MyButton *btn = (MyButton*)v;
            if ([btn.tagAsString isEqualToString:tagAsString])
                return btn;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. This seems easy! I've done it now. But now, when I have another button that deletes a button dependent on the ID. How would I do it? Just search for a button with the tagAsString that I'm searching for? Or what exactly? How can I compare it then?

Comment: To read identifier you can use btn.tagAsString. You can compare it as a NSString and you can remove button base on the comparison result if needed.

Comment: Hm, strange. I did as you said. Added the property to the interface that I also importet in the ViewController.m and also used the CustomButton instead of UIButton but it gives me an exception. What could the reason be?

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton setStringTag:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa7e2ee0'

Is it because my identifier starts with a `-` ? If yes, how can I escape that?

Comment: Because you use UIButton not CustomButton class. You need to cast it to CustomButton. Show the code where you get this error so I can help to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. Forgot to switch one UIButton with CustomButton. Thanks for the awesome help! Accepted and upvoted

Comment: If I may ask a last question. What would now be the equivalent to 

`UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:100];` ? When I'm calling from another method? I can't just use `testButton` right? Because the buttons are created dynamically and just the stringTag is different

Comment: It would be CustomButton *button = (CustomButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:100]; if your button with tag = 100 is CustomButton. If you use UIButton it will be UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:100];

Comment: Yes, but now I don't want to have the tag, I want to have the stringTag. Sorry for the misunderstanding. 

When I'm now in another method. How do I access a button based on the stringTag I gave it in another method?

Comment: @NewToObjectiveC see extended post.

Comment: Awesome that helped me so much!

Answer (score 2):

No need to create a whole new class that subclasses `UIButton` if we're just adding a new property we can just create a new category for `UIButton` by doing the following:

UIButton+properties_cat.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIButton.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface UIButton (properties_cat)

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *nameTag;

@end
```

UIButton+properties_cat.h

```
#import "UIButton+properties_cat.h"

@implementation UIButton (properties_cat)

// We can't use synthesize with categories so we have to use dynamic.
@dynamic nameTag;    

#pragma mark - Setters and Getters for nameTag Property
- (void)setNameTag:(NSString *)nameTag
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @"nameTag", nameTag, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (NSString *)nameTag
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @"nameTag");
}

@end
```

Then make sure to import the new class into your code by doing `#import "UIButton+properties_cat.h"`

Once we have `#imported` it we can now use it in that class like so

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btn setNameTag:@"my button name"];
```

Notice that we are still using `UIButton` and not created a pointless new class like `MyButton` we have just added that new property (`nameTag`) to the existing `UIButton` class.

**UPDATE**

This is an update based on comments in another answer.

So you want to be able to access a button that you have done in another method?

Well lets improve the code from above. Instead of applying the `nameTag` to `UIButton` lets apply it to `UIView` which `UIButton` inherits from. This will then allow us to apply `nameTag` to anything that inherits from `UIView` - `UILabel`, `UIButton` etc.

We also want to implement a new method called `viewWithName:` this will work the same way as `viewWithTag:` except it will check the `nameTag` instead of the `tag`.

So try using the following code:

UIView+cat.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIView.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface UIView (cat)

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *nameTag;  

- (UIView *)viewWithName:(NSString *)name;

@end
```

UIView+cat.m

```
#import "UIView+cat.h"

@implementation UIView (cat)

@dynamic nameTag;

#pragma mark - viewWithName: method

- (UIView *)viewWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    for(id view in [self subviews]) {
        // This if statement checks that the view is an instance of UIView class
        // or inherits from it, so it should return true if like UILabel.
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
            if([[view nameTag] isEqualToString:name]) {
                // This will return the first view that it comes across with the nameTag that equals name
                return view;
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

#pragma mark - Setters and Getters for nameTag Property
- (void)setNameTag:(NSString *)nameTag
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @"nameTag", nameTag, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (NSString *)nameTag
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @"nameTag");
}

@end
```

Now instead of importing `UIButton+properties_cat.h` we need to import `UIView+cat.h` this is because we don't need to create `UIButton+properties_cat.h` as `UIButton` inherits from `UIView` so it will pick the new property and method up.

So once we have imported `UIView+cat.h` we can then set our `UIButton` `nameTag` like:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btn setNameTag:@"my button name"];
```

then in another method that we want to access that button in we can do

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)[[self view] viewWithName:@"my button name"];
```

We add the cast because `viewWithName:` will return a `UIView` we want to make sure it is an instance of `UIButton`.

More information on [Customizing Classes with Categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)

If you need any more just ask.

Comment: +1 for effort. But I already solvled it with Greg's answer. Anyway, yours seems really good and logical because I wouldn't have to create subclasses. But I don't even know what you mean with `UIButton+properties_cat.h` but thanks!

Comment: It's just the convention of naming the file. `UIButton` because you are adding to `UIButton` and `properties_cat` because `properties_cat` is the name of your new category so the file name would become `UIButton+properties_cat.h` you could name it whatever you want but conventions sake it would be done like that.

Comment: Hi, yes, that's the part I understood. The part I didn't understand was, where I create these files and how do I create them or where do I write this. Do I just create a new file and name it UIButton+properties_cat.h? This was the part I didn't understand! I'm new. I'm sorry!

Comment: Yes, just like any other file you create and then you would just import it like any other file.

Comment: Ah okay! Then I was just confused by the naming conventions. Didn't know you can just add a `+` to the filenames. Thanks !!

Comment: As per the Apple Docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html a category would actually be better for you in this situation over subclassing. But it is your decision.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I will def. change it from subclass to categories when I finished with my current project. I just want to finish it now first to don't be stuck for some time again! Then I will change it. Thank you very much.

Comment: The plus (`+`) makes no difference what so ever you could do like `UIButtonPropertiesCat.h` or even just `PropertiesCat.h` but the convention says do it like `Class+CategoryName.fileExtension` check the link I have included.

Comment: @NewToObjectiveC based on comments to another answer I have improve my answer my applying the `nameTag` to `UIView` instead which will allow you to use it across anything that inherits from `UIView` which `UIButton` does. I have also implemented `viewWithName:` method which does the same as `viewWithTag:` except it checks the `nameTag` instead of the normal tag. If you need anything else just ask.

Answer (score 0):

The tag could only be an integer, if you need to use a NSString as identifier you have to subclass UIButton, add a new NSString property called buttonID (for example) and use that button.